How to add only unique items to HashSet
I have a list of items in the following format (Id, title, quantity, manufacturer)



Id
ProductId
Title
Quantity
Manufacturer




1
10
BluRay Player
3
Sony


2
20
CD Player
2
Sony


3
30
Fridge
1
LG


4
40
Washing Machine
1
Samsung



I want to get return these items by Manufacturer and total quantity of items for that Manufacturer as below



Manufacturer Id
Manufacturer Name
Quantity




1234
Sony
5


1235
LG
1


1236
Samsung
1



I have a method doing the below
public void GetManufacturerData()
{
     var manData = new HashSet<ManufacturerAndQuantity>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var mq = new ManufacturerAndQuantity();
            var manufac = myService.GetManufacturer(item.ProductId); 
            mq.Title = manufac.Title;
            mq.Id = manufac.Id;
            mq.Total += item.Quantity;

            if (!manData.Equals(c))
            {
                manData.Add(c);
            }
        }
}

The class (ManufacturerAndQuantity) is
public class ManufacturerAndQuantity : IEquatable<ManufacturerAndQuantity>
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Total{ get; set; } 

        public bool Equals(ManufacturerAndQuantity? other)
        {
            return this.Id.Equals(other.Id);
        }
    }

The issue im facing is im using a HashSet which according to my research means it would only add unique items and would disregard any duplicate items so wont add them to the list.
At present it is still adding the same item even though i have a check against Id so if the same ID appears i dont want to add it (in this case there are two items of the Sony brand so it only should be adding the entry once but in addition i would like to update the quantity so i have an accurate count of the total manufacturer products).
Where am i going wrong?
I checked MSDN and other online links for HashSet usage which all have similar ways to add and declare but i may need a bit more guidance on this.
Edit 1
Just modified the code slightly for the Manufacturer Id which should be ProductID. The only way for me to get the manufacturer details is passing the product ID to an external service which then returns the data for the manufacturer. There are no relations between the two as far as i can tell

Where did "Manufacturer Id" come from?

Ive just made an amendment to the code and explanation under Edit 1

if (!manData.Equals(c)) will never return true, as manData is a HashSet, and c probably a ManufacturerAndQuantity (not shown). You probably ment if(!manData.Contains(c)). Apart from this mq.Total += item.Quantity; will allways just assign the item.Quality, as mq is a new instance and its Total defaults to zero. So effectivly doing mq.Total = item.Quantity; is identical to mq.Total += item.Quantity; here.

if (!manData.Equals(c))
{
    manData.Add(c);
}

This makes no sense to me. There is no c defined, using Equals on the hashSet is most likely wrong, use SetEquals if you want to compare all items in the set, or Contains if you want to check membership. But Add returns a bool that says if value was added or not, so a separate Contains check is unnecessary.
public bool Equals(ManufacturerAndQuantity? other)
{
    return this.Id.Equals(other.Id);
}

If you are going to override equals you need to also override GetHashCode, otherwise the hashset will not work correctly. I would however recommend implementing a separate IEqualityComparer<T>, since I would generally expect reference equality for objects, and having a separate comparers allow the user to select what type of comparison he wants. HashSet allow a equality comparer to be specified on creation.
But if you want to count items it will be much easier to just use linq, something like:
items.Select(item => myService.GetManufacturer(item.ProductId))
     .GroupBy(mf => mf.Id)
     .Select(group => new ManufacturerAndQuantity(){
          Id = group.Key,
          Title = group.First().Title,
          Total = group.Count()
           });


I suppose the check for Hashset.Equals is ment to be a HashSet.Contains.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain you are probably right, Updated the first paragraph to mention this.
